# Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke() from within an action

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, invoke

i have a problem where I run part of my code using the `Dispatcher` class from `Application.Current` namespace. Then I want to construct a follow up operation using the `ContinueWith` method of the task returned by `Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

In this particular case, the follow up operation needs to be run from within the UI thread aswell, so it needs to be wrapped in the `Dispatcher.Invoke` again. This is how I got it to work:

```
Action doSomeMoreStuff = () => { this.MoreStuff; }
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.DoStuff).ContinueWith(x => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(this.DoSomeMoreStuff));
```

I want to keep it generic however, and there might be situations where I don't want the follow up code to be run from within the UI thread. So I tried to encapsulate the follow up code itself:

```
Action doSomeMoreStuff = () => { Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(this.MoreStuff); }
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.DoStuff).ContinueWith(x => this.DoSomeMoreStuff);
```

So as far as I understand this problem, I simply switched the position of the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()` call. However, the second approach does not work, the code does not get called, and I have no idea why.

What am I not getting here?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific, i.e. post an example?

Comment: [Here](http://tinyurl.com/mzlkyl7).

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke` is `void` returning. Either this isn't your real code, or it doesn't compile.

Comment: I'm comfortable with async await, thanks @HighCore. I was rather wondering what the benefits would be in this specific example. However, using async await is no option here, as it's part of legacy code written completely without async...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I edited the main post. I'm using a lambda expression to wrap the invoked method in an action, which makes `Dispatcher.Invoke()` return a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, ditching the `ContinueWith()`. It works

```
Action followUpAction = () => { };
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                async () =>
                    {
                        await this.DoStuff()

                        followUpAction();
                    });
```

Thanks for the helpful comments though.